# Has the rate at which items are heated changed with the July 30 patch?

Tags: spiral-knights

I am curious if the recent changes to how items are heated has influenced the rate at which they heat in the Clockworks.

I understand that you have to take items to a forge now to level them up, and that you may potentially get bonus heat in this process.  But in specific regards to the clockworks, has anything changed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: @aytimothy Disagree, as far as I'm aware heating behavior hasn't changed since this patch and I never got a clear answer. Can you elaborate on why you think this question is not relevant?

Answer (score 1):

According to [these patch notes](http://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/84873). I wouldn't say there are any changes regarding item heat rate anywhere, including the clockworks. (As of the July 30, 2013 patch.)